# Alpha PNG as Texture with nodes -> isn't totally transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I saw the threads on PNG alpha and made what It was recommended to do but I still have the problem although it brought me forward.

So I've a picture with transparent background (PNG), all seems ok for this picture.

I want to use it as a texture so I mapped it and it's maybe a bit deformed but seems also ok.

My problem is that the background is not totally black anymore but still on the edges.

Here is my node structure:

[image]
And here is the result:

[image]

I want to remove these black borders.

**EDIT:**

Here is the texture I want to apply:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

The [blend file](https://mega.co.nz/#!J4dQxZyK!Az2lrqTyjmam0jxcHMyfXcwgMV1TD2ScatD4Lg9PhKY) of the project (all the present textures are not used).

Comment: Please post the texture you are trying to apply; Try switching the transparent to the last, and the glossy to the first mix node.

Comment: Switching the nodes changes nothing and I'll edit my questions in few seconds

Comment: Would be easier if you just pack the file and upload the blend. I can't see any black borders, unless you're referring to the fact that you've made the mug transparent so that we can see the inside of the mesh.

Comment: Yeah, surely the black borders are shadows.

Comment: Yeah, ok I'll pack the blend! Thanks for your support :)

Comment: So, do you see something wrong? :)

Comment: SE doesn't notify me when a new comment is posted, only saw it now. 17mb for a mug? seriously? and next time use pasteall.org/blend

Comment: Ok, I'm a new to Blender and to BlenderSE (I come from Android Dev world and I've to do a bit of OpenGL/3d Modelling). Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything is working as it's supposed to. Those black borders you see are simply shadows cast by the mug onto itself because you've made a hole in the side with the transparency shader. It's easier to see from the side:

[image: side view]

It seems like you're trying to do something like this:

[image: decal]

You don't need a transparency shader because you're not making anything transparent - you simply need to make the background of the image the same colour as the rest of the mug, so just use a MixRGB node and the alpha of the image as the Fac.

You'll notice I added a math node as well - that's just to control how much of the glossy is being mixed in, since if you used the alpha directly without the math node it'd be mixing 100% glossy and 0% diffuse.

Comment: Wahou! Great! Sorry for disturbing you for a so simple problem! Thank you (I'd like to upvote you but I do not have enough rep... :( ).

Comment: Just a little last question, (I know that I'm annoying!), how did you do to get the same background color as the mug because I did what you did but we see a square that is not the same color as the mug. Which color did use in the mix?

Comment: That's what this site is for, happy to help :) If you hover the mouse over any colour value (like the one in your other material for the rest of the mug) and hit Ctrl+C, then hover over another colour value (the one on that Mix node) and Ctrl+V, it'll copy it there. (See: http://adaptivesamples.com/2014/02/01/cif-11-hover-copypaste/ )

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot, I much better understand these texture concepts yet!